# How do I POST a collection objects(with scaler attributes) using with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit

I've tried using Retrofits "Rest Builder" with interface methods containing Java "Collections" or    "Array List" as arguments, but always end up with 400 or 500 type errors.

```
Method in interface SvcApi

@POST(PATIENT_MEDSTAKEN + "/{patientID}")
public boolean submitMedsTaken(@Body ArrayList<MedicationTaken> medstaken, @Path("patientID") long id);

API build by:
private SvcApi symptomManagementService = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint(TEST_URL)
    .setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL).build()
    .create(SvcApi.class);
```

RESULT:

```
JUnit Failure trace: retrofit.RetrofitError:500 Server Error
```

Eclipse Console:

```
---> HTTP POST http://10.0.0.5:8080/patient/medicationstaken/1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 63
[{"Id":0,"taken":true,"timeTaken":1415132592031,"checkinId":2}]
---> END HTTP (63-byte body)
<--- HTTP 500 http://localhost:8080/patient/medicationstaken/1 (35ms)
: HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Length: 501
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
X-Application-Context: application
Server: Jetty(8.1.14.v20131031)
```

Comment: It's the server that produces the error, not the client's POST request. How does the REST end-point look like? Have you tried to perform the request using a REST client like Postman (http://www.getpostman.com/)?

Comment: I had the wrong ip address of my server I believe.